Files Not Seeding with Active Peers
I’m on a torrent tracker and I created and uploaded different files to it. I saw multiple people trying to leech the torrent but some times it doesn’t work.
Look here at this specific torrent:
It has 9 peers connected to it, that’s what my Transmission app says. On the tracker, I could see all eight of them. For some reason that I don’t know, they can’t get the files.

Here you could see that it did seed the file a bit but it stopped completely and hasn’t seeded no more again:

Why exactly can’t I seed the files?
